# Methods without external names in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, parameters, swift, naming

Is it possible to force all parameters of a Swift method to have only internal names?

I want the syntax to be terser in a helper method and all the parameter names gets in the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, use an `_` for the external name.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_347):

> If you do not want to provide an external name for the second or
>   subsequent parameter of a method, override the default behavior by
>   using an underscore character (_) as an explicit external parameter
>   name for that parameter.

***Note:** You don't need an `_` on the first parameter, it won't have an external name by default.*

```
class SomeClass {
    func someFunction(someString: String, _ someInt: Int, _ someDouble: Double) {
        /* ... */
    }
}

var c = SomeClass()
c.someFunction("foo", 1, 3.14)
```